# If else statement in Vbscript for Secure CRT

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

I am having trouble executing if else statement in vba for secure crt, it seems the statement `if` is not being understood by the complier.

I wrote a code so that I could login in using host name "ABCDE" and if I get an error message saying that the host name is incorrect then I will login in using the host ip

```
crt.Screen.Send "ssh 22008130@ABCDE"   &  Chr(13)

If

Crt.Screen.WaitForString ("ssh: ABCDE: Temporary failure in name resolution",10) = True

crt.Screen.Send "ssh 22008130@100.127.16.159"   &  Chr(13)

crt.Screen.WaitForString "Password:"

crt.Screen.Send "Asdf@123" & chr(13)

crt.Screen.Send "exit" & chr(13)

Else If

 

crt.Screen.WaitForString "Password:"

crt.Screen.Send "Asdf@123" & chr(13)

crt.Screen.WaitForString"ABCDE#"

crt.Screen.Send "exit" & chr(13)

end if

end sub
```

**Microsoft VBScript compilation error

Error: Syntax error

File: C:\Users\22005873\Desktop\Data for script Script for Sfp
DATA\SFPSCRIPT FORERRORINNAME.vbs

Line: 9**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems in the code:

### `If` needs `Then`

You are missing a `Then`. The correct syntax as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84))

> ```
> ' Block syntax: 
> If condition Then
>    [statements]
> [ElseIf condition-n Then
>    [elseifstatements]] . . .
> [Else
>    [elsestatements]]
> End If 
>
> Single-Line syntax:
> If condition Then statements [Else elsestatements ]
> ```

### `Else If` <> `ElseIf`

Again, refer to the documentation. In this case, within the `Else` block there is a new `If` block that is missing a `Then` and an `End If`.
Presumably the correct syntax in this case is `ElseIf`

### Too much newlines

VBScript syntax is line delimited. That means you have to put the `If condition Then` on a single line.

### No indentation

The compiler/interpreter doesn't care about indentation, but us mere humans need indentation to be able to follow the code. Using indentation correctly will help you spot syntax mistakes, like missing an `End If`.